# How to Install pdfimages in El Capitan?

Tags: command-line, install, pdf, homebrew

I am reviewing the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/150106/25388) about *Extracting embedded images from a PDF*.
It is not in Homebrew.

---

How can you install `pdfimages` in OS X El Capitan?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can install via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) with the following command:

```
brew install poppler
```

Comment: Can `pdf2image` be the same command as `pdfimages`?

Comment: @Masi sorry my mistake. I update my answer.

Comment: Can `poppler` be the same as `pdfimages`?

Comment: Yes. The package contains pdfimages.

Answer (score 9):

Another command-line program that can extract bitmap images from PDF files is the command-line version of the Unarchiver app called 'unar'. (Doesn't need Homebrew or anything to install.) The command is simply
`unar filename.pdf`

http://unarchiver.c3.cx/commandline

(The original GUI-based Unarchiver.app does this as well.)

Comment: Do you have any idea how well Unar does with vector images?

Comment: Unar doesn't convert vector to bitmap images, nor does it save individual document pages.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 You can "extract" any vector data from a PDF on macOS using the built-in Preview.app! Open the "thumbnails" sidebar that shows miniatures of the pages, select the page containing the graphic you are interested in, `Cmd+C`, then `Cmd+N`. You now got a copy of that page. Now crop it using "Tools -> Rectangular Selection", select your graphic, then "Tools -> Crop" (or `Cmd+K`). Save as PDF, done! Optionally, you can feed this to the command line tool `pdfcrop` which will crop any remaining space around it. It doesn't get much better than that!